# npx react-native link dose not working for me

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm, npx, react-native-linking

I'm trying to use this (https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4) to add font but I have problem with this part...

```
npx react-native link
```

this command don't shows anything to me... anything; and then console line "C:\Users****\WebstormProjects\myFirstProject> appears again. like I didn't wrote any command at first. what's wrong?

Comment: Make sure your `react-native.config.js` is a JavaScript file instead of TypeScript file (that was the mistake I made haha) 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a `react-native.config.js` then you can use `react-native link` command.

Example:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/Montserrat', './src/assets/fonts/Nunito', './src/assets/fonts/Newsreader', './src/assets/fonts/Anton', './src/assets/fonts/Gilroy'],
};
```

Comment: thank, but I did it and in the terminal I've got nothing, even a single error... I wish I could give an screenshot

Comment: Can you copy the error code or u got the same as above?

Comment: Unrecognized command "link"

Comment: @DánielBoros - if you add static files other than fonts in this way, how can you import/reference these files directly in React Native code?

Comment: Do you think about videos/images for example?

Answer (score 10):

Use **`npx react-native-asset`** for `react-native` > 0.69

Comment: As of 10th August 2022. This should be the accepted answer. Once you add your fonts to an `./assets/fonts` directory and add the `react-native.config.js`. `react-native-asset` will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think, 'link' has been removed in v0.69. Here are the steps to add custom fonts.

1. Copy the font files to "./assets/fonts" folder.
2. Add the react-native.config.js file to project root with the code bellow

   ```
   module.exports = {
   assets:['./assets/fonts']}
   ```
3. For android no need to link but in the ios additionally follow the below steps.

   Open the ios project in Xcode. Drag and drop font files on to "Copy Bundle Resources". [image]

Then open the "Info.plist" and add the fonts.
[image]

After that goto "Product" menu and hit the "Clean Build Folder". Then start the Metro and start your application.

Answer (score 0):

in RN +0.69 some times when you are trying to add your custom fonts, you may saw this error :

**`'react-native-asset' is not recognized as an internal or external command`**

If you get this error first `install yarn add -D react-native-asset` as a dev dependency then run `npx react-native-asset`